# how do i change the priority of a session ID connected to my server?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql

I am running sql server 2008 on a windows 7 64 bit machine.

I am running a query at the same time as another session ID, and I would like to lower the priority of the other session ID because my process is more critical.

The other process is an SSIS package that is running.

Is it at all possible to change the priority of the processes while the jobs are running?

Is it possible to change the priority of a specific USER ID?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're using an edition of SQL Server that has the Enterprise Edition engine (Enterprise Edition, Enterprise Evaluation Edition, or Developer Edition), you can use [Resource Governor](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee151608%28v=SQL.100%29.aspx) to manage resources based on a user-defined function that can include the server login. Please see the link to find out if this is an appropriate solution.

It is not possible, however, to change a running process' priority -- Resource Governor has to be configured before the connection comes in.

Comment: If you're having performance issues it might be better to address these directly first.