# Programmatically set DB connection priority

Tags: c#, multithreading, odbc, database-connection

We have a C# app that opens multiple ODBC connections to various databases (mostly Oracle and SQL Server).

Is there a way to programmatically tell the DB which connection to give the highest priority to?

For instance, if I have Con1, Con2, and Con3 all connecting to an ODBC database, I want to be able to tell the database to treat Con2 as the highest priority over any other connections so it'll prioritize that workload first.

While I could set a C# thread-priority, this won't work because while the C# thread may run at the highest, it'll still run only as fast as the underlying database connection (unless I'm wrong and the C# thread priority is passed through?).

Comment: Great question. I've often wondered this myself. And the implications if everyone set their connection to be treated as the 'highest' priority.

Comment: The goal isn't clear to me. Don't you ultimately need to run all of the queries? In which case a priority queue would get the job done. And since the work is done on separate DB servers, why does the order matter? In which case the `async` features built into C# will do what you need. If you're really worried about processing results, it still seems like a priority queue is your friend here... but on the resulting IDataReader or DataTable objects, not on the connections.

Comment: _Is there a way to programmatically tell the DB which connection to give the highest priority to?_  any connection can serve your app? if no, why are the others there? if yes, how do you difference priority vs preference? just use "your side" code to connect against what you want choosing as you want.  Priority is for servers who serve many, not for clients who choose what to do.  I will keep a down vote up to your explanation.

Answer (score 1):

I haven't used it, but it sounds like you can use Oracle's [Database Resource Manager](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28310/dbrm001.htm) to assign different priorities to different sessions.

> In an environment with multiple concurrent users sessions that run jobs with differing priorities, all sessions should not be treated equally. The Resource Manager enables you to classify sessions into groups based on session attributes, and to then allocate resources to those groups in a way that optimizes hardware utilization for your application environment.

This [related question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14131289/4794) mentions SQL Server's [Resource Governor](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee151608(v=SQL.100).aspx).

If you want to set priorities between two different database systems, like Oracle and SQL server, I think it will be less flexible. The best I can think of would be to set the process priority for one of the database systems lower than the other. The resource manager and governor sound like they will let you limit how many resources any one query can use, but that may lead to situations where there are no other tasks, and the low-priority task ends up leaving some of the processor speed unused.

Comment: Will it allow us to set priority among set of heteric DBMS (non-Oracle ones to be precise)?

Comment: I suspect it will be less flexible for setting priority among heterogenous database sessions, @TalhaIrfan, but I added some suggestions to my answer.